# One line exaggerated execution time

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, expectation-maximization

I'm developing a program with OpenCV in C++. The program it's working fine. The line of code that I've put below normally needs some miliseconds to execute but sometimes the same line needs 5, 10 or even 50 seconds.

```
clustEM.trainE(resP.colRange(0, 2), clusters.means, clusters.covs, clusters.weights, logLikeli, labels);
```

Do you have any idea what could be the problem?? The inputs are normally the same size.

Comment: time for em goes exponentioal with the sample-col-size.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I know it and how I say in the first post the size isn't the problem because with 5000 elements sometimes the time is more than the time with 9000 elements.... Any other idea??

Comment: Can you provide the arg values for short & long time ?

Comment: Sure. Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/go45sjzj9tm5okh/times.txt?dl=0
The first column is the size and the second the time (ms).
The problem is here:
5282 106.609
4897 8342.179  <-- 8seconds!!
5128 22413.789 <-- 22seconds!!
5258 106.547

Comment: How different are the samples in those 2 cases? It could be a problem of converging?

Comment: The samples are very similar about data and size...
I don't understand you... converging?
Someone have any idea about my problem?
THANKS

Comment: Someone could show me the way to find the error?
THANKS!!